# is this structure possible? (demand + something (or someone) + to infinite) cf) I want to know how to migrate this question to English Learner site

Tags: grammar

I think demand is used as case 1, case 2 or case 3.

case 1. demand + object
ex) I demanded an explanation. (Cambridge Dictionary)

case 2. demand to infinite
ex) I demand to see the manager. (Cambridge Dictionary)

case 3. demand + that clause
ex) She demanded that he return the books he borrowed from her. (Cambridge Dictionary)

---

[Question]

These days, many cities and some countries impose a special tax on sugar. They **demand** drinks and foods that are high in sugar **to have** this additional tax.

---

I think that the structure (demand + sth + to infinite) is possible. but I can't find any reference. (even, some website posting indicates that such structure is false.)

the structure (demand + sth + to infinite) is impossible? If so, how can I understand the sentence structure?

Comment: That looks awkward. Consider rewording as either “they require ... to have ...” or “they demand that ... have ...”.

Comment: Your understanding seems correct. But it's not a usual construction with "demand" (although it's common with similar verbs like "want").

Comment: The example sentence is poorly constructed, and separates two constituents that would be flat-out ungrammatical if placed together without intervening material.  Saying *_We demand them to have this tax_ is terrible grammar. First, _have_ is not an appropriate active verb for the complement of _demand_, and second, _demand_ does not take a [B-Equi infinitive complement; only A-Equi, with no intervening NP](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), as in (2)

Answer (score 0):

You command someone to do something. You demand that someone do something. No logical reason but that's English. A soft drink lacks volition so you can't demand that it do something, but you can use the passive voice. "They demand that food and drink high in sugar be taxed at a higher rate" or "be subject to an additional tax."